# PHP AJAX Search Function Using stristr and substr

Tags: php, ajax

On **w3schools** there is a page on PHP and AJAX and it uses a text box to search an array of names.

However the function they used seems rather peculiar because;

- If you search "Joh", **Johanna** pops up
- If you search "An", **Anna** pops up
- If you search "Johanna", **Anna, Johanna** pops up
- But if you search "Johann", only **Johanna** pops up

This seems very odd because I read the PHP documentation and the stristr function uses a needle in the hastack method to detect whether a string can be found in the other, and in this search box you don't have to search the ENTIRE string for it to be find as evidenced above.

So can somebody explain how the **second if statement** searches a string. I understand the rest. - reffered from **w3schools**

```
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

    $hint = "";

    // lookup all hints from array if $q is different from "" 
    if ($q !== "") {
        $q = strtolower($q);
        $len=strlen($q);
        foreach($a as $name) {
            if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) {
                if ($hint === "") {
                    $hint = $name;
                } else {
                    $hint .= ", $name";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Output "no suggestion" if no hint was found or output correct values 
    echo $hint === "" ? "no suggestion" : $hint;
```

The entire code cannot be pasted here. However, if necessary it is all at the bottom of **w3schools** [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp?)
Feel free to also test out the search box too so that you can understand what I am saying further.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it wasn't correct. sorry

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is the code using the stristr is not being used correctly, or as you intuitively expect.

The right solution would be to switch the haystask and needle like this:

```
if (stristr($name,$q))
```

Although it would still keep the ambiguity. Probably the right way to do it would be using a regular expression function like preg_match and searching a match from the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) { //this if condition to look for string $q's first occurence in string $name
                if ($hint === "") { //this if condition is for when the foreach loop executes for the first time, there is no value in $hint, to assign that value we execute this if condition
                    $hint = $name;
                } else {
                    $hint .= ", $name"; // for rest of the foreach loops this else condition will only execute
                }
            }
```

Comment: @BilalMaqsood, read the OP requirements and then comment here.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($a as $name)
```

This line takes each value from array $a[] one by one in $name variable

```
  if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len)))`
```

Now this line returns a positive return value if the expression inside is true.it will be when the entered text($q) is available to be searched. if the substring of starting length of letters of $q are not equal then negative value will be returned , so if statement will not execute.

Answer (score 0):

SUMMARY
This occurs because stristr searches from the beginning of the string, from left to right, and is trying to match names from the database against what the user has inputted as limited by the number of characters that the user has entered.

DETAILED RESPONSE
stristr is searching through a haystack, the query that the user has inputted ($q) in the HTML form, for a needle, the value of the array ($a - defined in gethint.php) that is being looped through.

```
if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len)))
```

So stristr is searching for names (from $a array in gethint.php) within the query string ($q) that the user has inputted. But stristr is not searching for whole names, its search is limited by substr. Substr is set to return all of the characters (0) it finds in the $name entry, limited by the number of characters that the user has inputted in query string $q.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

```
echo substr('abcdef', 0, 8);  // abcdef
echo substr('abcdef', 0, 4);  // abcd
```

When the user types “Johan” there is a match in the $a array of names for Johan, and so the if condition is met and the statement executes: set $hint to that entire $a entry ($name) (i.e. Johanna). This is important because it stops “Jos” returning “Johanna”. Unless there is an exact match between what has been typed and what is in the array, it doesn’t return anything.

```
if ($hint === "") {
$hint = $name;
} else {
$hint .= ", $name";
}
```

When the user types “Johann” the only match in the $a array is Johann, but when they type “Johanna” then there are two matches, there is “Johanna” and “Anna”.

To further illustrate the point, imagine I typed “Ravig” and the array included:

```
Avi
Ravi
Raviel
Ravigdor
Ravishy
```

This would return Avi, Ravi and Ravigdor, but not any others, and that would be appropriate.